# Mock a public method of the class being tested

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit, mockery

I'm trying to unit test a class where one public method (method 1) uses another public method (method 2) of the same class within it. E.g.

```
class MyClass {
    public function method1()
    {
        $var = $this->method2();
        // Do stuff with var to get $answer
        return $answer;
    }

    public function method2()
    {
        // Do complex workings out to get $var
        return $var;
    }
}
```

Now, `method2` is already unit tested and I don't want to build up an argument for it to actually call it whilst testing `method1`. I just want to mock up `method2` and define in my test what would be returned. This is what I have:

```
function test_method1()
{
    $myClass = new MyClass();

    $mockedMyClass = Mockery::mock('MyClass');
    $mockedMyClass->shouldReceive('method2')->once()->andReturn([1,2,3,4]); // mocked $var returned to be used in the rest of method1

    $answer = $myClass->method1();
    // Assertions
}
```

Clearly this doesn't work as the method being tested is in the same class as contains the method being mocked, so there's no way to pass in the mocked class as a dependency. What's the best way to mock just method2?

Comment: Whenever you feel the need to mock a method of the class you are testing, this is an indicator that the class should be split in two, and tested individually. Because if you feel the need to mock because "I don't want to build up an argument", the class likely does too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Partial Mock](http://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/partial_mocks.html#traditional-partial-mock) functionality of the testing framework that permit you to test the same class you are marked as mocked.
As example, suppose the your modified class:

```
<?php


namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Model;


class MyClass {
    public function method1()
    {
        $var = $this->method2();
        $answer = in_array(3, $var);
        // Do stuff with var to get $answer
        return $answer;
    }

    public function method2()
    {
        // Do complex workings out to get $var
        return array();
    }
}
```

And tested as follow:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Tests;


class MyClassTest  extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    function test_method1()
    {

        $mockedMyClass = \Mockery::mock('Acme\DemoBundle\Model\MyClass[method2]');
        $mockedMyClass->shouldReceive('method2')->once()->andReturn([1,2,3,4]); // mocked $var returned to be used in the rest of method1

        $answer = $mockedMyClass->method1();
        $this->assertTrue($answer);        // Assertions
    }

}
```

Hope this help